# How does a MIPS CPU power down?

Tags: assembly, mips, system-calls, exit

How does a hypothetical OS kernel on a MIPS I compliant CPU actually implement a syscall 10, thus halting all execution, and power down?

The long story:

I'm currently building a MIPS emulator, based specifically on the MIPS I architecture specification; I have dealt with (almost) the whole ISA that comes with it, and made some deep and interesting discoveries along the way. I'm also dabbling on the privileged resources, and anything involving the system coprocessor (COP0).

I am intent on writing a basic kernel that handles exceptions/syscalls/traps in a privileged context, mostly to simulate how syscalls are executed from a kernel-mode standpoint; one that is currently stumping me is the termination syscall, code 10. I expected to find some (privileged) instruction that does halt execution like `HLT` does to x86; however the closest thing to it I can find is the `WAIT` instruction.

`WAIT` is actually designed to switch the CPU to low-power mode and *wait* for interrupts, and is found in the ISA, therefore making it available in user mode too; there is no indication of terminating execution, although I could figure out some way to fabricate it from this.

However; I feel that I'm on a wrong track, and the volumes I-A, II-A and III of the MIPS specification are not helping me much anymore. To put it in other words: does somebody know what actually goes on in a real MIPS CPU after a syscall 10 is executed?

Comment: `HLT` also waits for interrupts, it's not a power down. Actual power down on x86 can be done via ACPI, but that's for PCs not MIPS devices

Comment: _"what goes on in a real MIPS CPU after a syscall 10 is executed?"_ Note that system call 10 being used to terminate execution is a software construct implemented by various MIPS simulators. It's not something that's part of the CPU architecture. You can look at SPIM's implementation [here](https://github.com/petru-dimitriu/qtspim/blob/master/CPU/syscall.c#L199) and [here](https://github.com/petru-dimitriu/qtspim/blob/master/CPU/run.c#L1103).

Comment: You mean actually powering off the whole machine, so that it stays off until someone comes along to switch it back on?  I don't know about MIPS, but typically this is a feature of external hardware provided by the system designer, not of the CPU itself.  You'd accomplish it with appropriate I/O commands to that external hardware according to its documentation, and it won't necessarily be the same for all MIPS-based machines.

Comment: Halting the cpu wouldnt power down a device except for an mcu and it doesnt power down it goes into a low power state.  If you want to power down the system it has nothing to do with the instruction set or cpu itself just like the fans or pixels or turning off the screen to save power, it is external to the cpu and done with software made for that system (just like putting pixels on a display, or talking to a keyboard, or laptop battery, etc).  CPU's generally dont have a halt as it doesnt make sense outside test vector simulations or the like.  Normally a cpu stops when the power is removed.

Comment: The "syscall 10" you're talking about is only supported by the MARS, or other emulators, so it's not actually implemented in hardware at all.  The simulator simply stops simulating.  A real MIPS operating system running on a real MIPS CPU would offer different operating system services with different semantics.

Comment: @harold Should've checked that before making assumptions... thanks; it did clear some confusion of mine; maybe `wait` is what I was looking for after all. I may accept it as an answer.

Comment: @Michael @NateEldredge @old_timer @RossRidge Maybe my question wasn't clear on the subject as I hoped, I'm aware of the system codes being implementation-dependant, I found a good answer about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20368672/3909752); my project is actually based on MARS's source code. However, since any MIPS snippet with termination I've seen while searching the Net, including some answers on SO, have this idiom, it did make me wonder if there was an actual (and maybe, de facto standard) way of performing termination. As in, why not just define `wait 0` as terminator?

Comment: `syscall 10` seems more analogous to process termination rather than power down.  I say this because the MARS & SPIM simulators, feel more like they are simulating a single process with some helper syscalls than a complete processor running an operating system.

Comment: Yes, we can write an exception handler that works like a mini os to support thread creation.  But the clocks don't function well enough to do proper time slicing and both of these simulators get mad if you put a value into the stack pointer register too far out of the normal (single threaded) stack range, and, we can't do virtual memory so no address space isolation.

Comment: @ErikEidt Yeah, I'm definielty not going the `multi` route, lest many things become impractical, if not just impossible, to re-implement (e.g. the backstepping mechanism). Indeed I'm just trying to write a toy kernel that just handles exceptions/traps, and most probably craft some basic virtual devices for functions like printing stuff or inputting data, that's it.

Comment: All the example MIPS assembly code you're going to find on the web is going to be for simulators since no one has an actual MIPS computer to run MIPS code on.  If you want to find out what a real operating system does on real hardware you trying looking at the Linux sources, as it has a MIPS port.  Note that neither the `exit` nor `reboot` system calls use syscall number 10 on Linux MIPS.

Comment: `syscall 10` is just the equivalent of `mov ax,4C00h int 21h` on MS-DOS. It closes your program and goes back to whatever it was doing before your program was run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> syscall 10

`Syscall` numbers are always operating system specific: The MIPS version of Linux uses completely different system call numbers than the SPIM emulator.

For this reason you should better not talk about "*syscall 10*" but about "*syscall 10 in SPIM*" (or whatever OS or emulator you are talking about) to avoid misunderstandings.

> How does a hypothetical OS kernel on a MIPS I compliant CPU actually implement a syscall 10 ...

First of all: On the "SPIM" emulator, "syscall 10" is `exit`, not `shutdown`.

`exit` does not power down the computer but it stops the currently running task in a multi-tasking OS. The OS simply frees all resources of the current task (e.g. it marks the memory used by the task as "free") and does not schedule that task any longer.

All other tasks (and the OS and the CPU) keep on running.

> ... that does halt execution like `HLT` does ...

I'm not sure what `HLT` *really* does on modern x86 CPUs. On early Intel CPUs, the `HLT` instruction simply performed a jump back to itself until an interrupt occurred.

This means that the CPU did not execute the `HLT` instruction once, but it executed the instruction again and again (just like a `JMP` instruction in an endless loop).

If an interrupt occurs, that endless loop is broken (execution continues after the next instruction after `HLT`); if no interrupt occurs (this can be forced using the combination `CLI` + `HLT`), the CPU goes into an endless loop, but it is not powered down.

> ... halting all execution, and power down?

This is `shutdown`:

CPU cores *typically* don't have this feature; some hardware outside the CPU is doing this.

Just like all other hardware (keyboard, screen, disk ...), the responsible hardware unit is accessed using an I/O address:

When connected to a CPU that does not supports special I/O address space (such as `IN` and `OUT` instructions on x86), "regular" (memory) addresses are used.

Let's say the power supply unit is connected to your system at address 0xF1234560 (just as an example) and the power is switched off when writing value 0x789 to that address. In this case the following sequence would power off your system:

```
LUI a0, 0xF123
ORI a1, zero, 0x789
SW a1, 0x4560(a0)
```

And because this hardware unit is found *outside* the CPU, you won't find any information about it in the CPU manuals.

And of course different hardware units working completely differently are used in different types of computers using the same CPU type! (So there is no "typical MIPS power supply unit".)

In the 1990s (when most MIPS desktop computers were built) it was very common that the system could not be powered down by the software at all but some message was printed to the screen ("*Please power down the computer*") and the CPU was simply going to an endless loop...